# How to insert images into database using a string containing a URI by SqlParameterCollection?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert an image into a database table in the following code. When I execute this code, an exception pops up saying

> Cannot bulk load. The file "@value" does not exist

`textBox1.Text` is the resource that URI for the image contain.

What am I doing wrong ?

Is it possible to add images like what I have tried ?

Code examples will be appreciated .

Thanks

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    String insertPicture = @"INSERT INTO Images (UserImage) VALUES ((Select BulkColumn from Openrowset (Bulk '@value', Single_Blob) as Image))";

    SqlParameterCollection parameters = new SqlCommand().Parameters;
    parameters.AddWithValue("@value", textBox1.Text);

    _dataAccess.DBConnect();
    int result = _dataAccess.SqlInsert(insertPicture, parameters);
    _dataAccess.DBDisconnect();

    if (result > 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: Figured it out myself  .. I just replaced "@value" with  "textbox.text" in the sql command and it worked  ..

Comment: Nilaksha, great that you solved it. Please post as an answer what you just mentioned was the fix, and then accept that answer. This will make it clearer to others that might run into this.